# Hibernate's generator class not really working?

Tags: java, hibernate

Asking this question here after hours of frustration with me and my Eclipse. Hoping to find some respite here.

I'm trying to save a pojo object into MySQL database via Hibernate 3.0. Basically my requirement is: I need to assign the id for the object before save and not let Hibernate do it for me.

For this I looked up in the documentation and saw that `<generator class="assigned"/>` perfectly fits my bill. Consequently I updated by `.hbm.xml` file with the following for the `id`:

```
<id name="id" type="int">
    <column name="ID" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

My pojo matches `.hbm.xml` file to the T.

I'm setting all the parameters including the `ID` of my pojo and calling Hibernate's `saveOrUpdate(object)` method.

If it's of any help, the `ID` column of my database table has "auto-inc" disabled.

Unbelievably, when I look at the database table contents, a row has been inserted with Hibernate's own ID and not what I had set.

How's it possible? Is there anything else affecting the `ID`? Am I missing on something? What's the work around?

My `hibernate.properties` looks like below(if it's of any help):

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbdbdbdbdb
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.pool_size=10
jdbc.batch_size=30
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.current_session_context_class=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: Java crowd is dying?. Only 6 views so far. :(

Comment: @pavanlimo: hint: claiming that some (widely used) library or one of its features is simply "not working" is unlikely to lead to many views (or answers, for that matter). Asking why it doesn't work for you might be more appreciated.

Comment: Since the question has proven to be wrong (as you posted yourself below). People trying to solve your (non-existing) problem now would only waste their time.

Comment: I reckon they(people) will try to google the same way as I did, only to realize that the problem may be with their IDE(after heading to this page of course). I think we are being strict here :). However, if all(5) of you think the question is "ambiguous" then do go ahead and close it.

Comment: @pavanlimo: Please don't understand this to be an attack on you. The question is well-formulated and well-presented. It's just that the information in the question has turned out to have nothing to do with the eventual solution (making sure Tomcat uses the latest version of the source). Therefore, it is misleading and can't be answered in its current furom.

Comment: No sir. I'm speaking with the spirit of SO. Just like you. Absolutely nothing to do with "me". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, hoax alarm!. It was really an issue with `Eclipse`-`Tomcat` integration. I had to clean up `Tomcat`'s directories and republish before the `hbm` files could take effect.

**Tip:** If you run ant within Eclipse, be sure to keep refreshing Eclipse workspace every now and then. Learning some things the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom sequence generator class to return ids suitable to your requirement. For more details follow: http://danu-javastuff.blogspot.com/2009/01/custom-id-generator-class-for-hibernate.html